# 'RandomOverSampler' object has no attribute '_validate_data'

Tags: python, imblearn

Hi I am getting following error can anyone suggest me what could be wrong?

When I am calling, `os.fit_sample(X,y)`

> 'RandomOverSampler' object has no attribute '_validate_data'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem is originating possibly from the version of `scikit-learn` installed in your system. As mentioned in the [release documentation](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/releases) of `imblearn` that the minimum `scikit-learn` version should be `0.23.0`. So, reinstall the scikit-learn as the following :

```
conda install scikit-learn=0.23.0
```

This should hopefully resolve the problem.